# Best way to handle submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently I have a giant SVN repo that I migrated over to git with `svn2git`. The repo has two top level directories, software and dependencies. Dependencies doesn't change very often and it's quite large. My thought was to make it a submodule. I used `git filter-branch` to spilt the repo apart. I have now a software.git and dependencies.git repos.

Should I make a super project that contains the two repos or add dependencies as a submodule to software? I'm open to other suggestions.

Edit: The superproject would only contain the software and dependencies repos. I want to be able to correlate version X.Y.Z between both repos. They are both needed for a delivery.

Comment: The short answer is _it depends_. I'm afraid you'll have to be a bit more specific. For example, would the root project contain anything else other than _software_ and _dependencies_? Do you want to keep the history of the root project separate from the other two?

Comment: The superproject would only contain the two repos. I want to correlate vX.Y.Z between software and dependencies.

Comment: For that case (tying together revisions) I'd make a superproject consisting solely of the two submodules, yes. It's (obviously) not the only way, but it directly solves the problem you want, which is to have a list of pairs of commit hashes, and it provides a nice way to clone both repositories and check out the right hashes.

Comment: @torek What about adding dependencies as a submodule of software?

Comment: You could do that; the effects are similar but now you can view the software repo as the controller and the dependencies as controlled. With the separate superproject, both "software" and "dependencies" are peers. In practice the usage is probably about the same, and all the systems I've used tend to use controller-controlled instead of superproject+(set-of-peers) but from a theoretical perspective, if they're loosely coupled, I like the set-of-peers better.